# set cursor to middle line on vim startup

Tags: vim

I would like to sometimes invoke vim with a startup command (by passing `-c "something"` on the command line) that centers the cursor in the middle of the screen - the same effect as if I pressed `M` immediately after opening vim. However the `-c` option only accepts ex commands, which `M` is not. Is this possible (and how if so)?

For background, in combination with `scrolloff = 999`, this would allow me to begin scrolling forward with `j` immediately upon opening vim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use normal mode commands with the `normal` (or `norm`) ex command

```
vim -c 'norm M' <filename>
```

Take a look at `:h :normal`

Answer (score 0):

```
-c "let &scrolloff=999-&scrolloff"
```

should do the trick.